# Why can't I change a private member of a class from a friend class in a different namespace?

Tags: c++

I am finding trouble accessing a private member of a class from a friend class.

The class that holds the private member I want to change and the class where the change is made are in different namespaces.

The friend class is defined after the class holding the data, so I've tried to forward declare the friend class outside the namespace.

g++ says that I can't modify the member because it's private, visual studio seems to think it's fine.

Am I doing some weird non-standard thing here? Why can't I change the member? Here is a simplified snippet that represents my problem:

```
struct S;

namespace N
{
    class A
    {
        int m;
    public:
        A():m(5){};
        friend struct S;
    };

}

using namespace N;

struct S
{
    A& a;
    S(A& a):a(a) {}
    void changeA(){ a.m = 9; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    S s(a);
    s.changeA();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
friend struct ::S;
```

what you are really doing with

```
friend struct S;
```

is declaring as friend the class N::S (which is defined nowhere).

Edit: To back up my idea that gcc behavior is correct and VC++ has a bug.

7.3.1.2/3

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class or
>   function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost
>   enclosing namespace. [...]  When looking for a prior declaration of a
>   class or function introduced by a friend declaration, scopes outside the
>   innermost enclosing namespace scope are not considered.

Comment: @Jacobo: Because it's valid.  You can always `friend` a struct or class, even if it hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: @Jacob friend members don't need to actually exist. This is really helpful when your friend member is a template but nobody uses the template. Plus what aschepler said.

Comment: @aschepler maybe the declaration, but it should not allow me to modify A in a class that is not a friend

Comment: @Jacobo, my opinion is that accepting your code is a bug in VC++. (neither Como nor Sun CC, the two other compilers I've currently access to; accept it).

Comment: @aschepler: The assignment is not valid. OP is wondering why VC++ accepts it, now that he knows that it's not valid.

Answer (score 5):

Because `friend struct S;` declares `N::S` class but you need `::S` class.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing out `friend struct ::S;`.

At the moment, the non-existent `N::S` is assumed. This fix specifies the global namespace, a bit like how the leading `/` on a Linux path specifies the filesystem root.